# Alamofire response parse

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire, how parsing results with **UTF-8**?

I have try utf8text["parameter"] but not working

```
Alamofire.request("http://*******.com/alamofire.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
        }
     case .failure(let error):
         print(error)
     }
}
```

I am using Alamofire 4.7
swift 4
xcode 9.2

Comment: The code looks good. What error are you getting? Does your server return a correctly formatted JSON response?

Comment: Hi Gereon, the result from the server is correct but i am not parsing result.
result = {"username":"username","password":"1234567"}

Comment: Please include the full HTTP response including headers. (Use `curl -i` or something similar).

Comment: how will I do? .

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use the response string instead of decoding the data to UTF-8:

```
Alamofire.request("http://*******.com/alamofire.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseString { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print(response.value)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Does this print the correct result?